# is it possible to change sheet name with apache poi MS excel java android

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, rename, spreadsheet

is there any way to update existing sheet name of MS Excel file knowing that I am using apache poi  in my android app

I can create a sheet with my custom name

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("my custom name");
```

but when I want to copy another sheet to this one , the name also is copied and my custom name is crashed

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
workbook.setSheetName(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet), "newName");
```

Comment: I am getting the following error while using setsheetName method in Apache POI.

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..3)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

If you already know the sheet index, simply call

```
workbook.setSheetName(sheet-index, "my sheet name");
```

where sheet-index is the sheet number (0 based)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, while using setSheetName, I get IllegalArgumentException that : Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..0) even when I have just 1 sheet.
So, I just did this and it worked.

```
    workbook.getCTWorkbook().getSheets().getSheetArray(indexOfSheet).setName(sheetName);
```